# Selenium: does a js object exist on a website?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am quite new with Selenium and not a coder. I have to test if a specific js object exist on a website.

The java script is in the `<head>` section. This script creates a new js object. Now I want to write a test case with Selenium, which tests if the object is created.

I tried it with `findElement`, but it seems not working for a js object.
Tried this (with variations):

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

WebElement we4 = driver.findElement(By.name("myJSObject"));
```

Any ideas how I can test this object?

Comment: Pleas paste your html code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are executing `WebElement we4 = driver.findElement(By.name("myJSObject"));`, you are actually looking for an html element that has a name `myJSObject`.

What you can do is executing a script that will return the value of your object :

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
Object result = jse.executeScript("return window.myJSObject;");
```

Comment: @Anik I know java and javascript is the same thing, but I only use the second one ;-)

Comment: It almost worked.

First I had to cast this expression:
String result = (String) jse.executeScript("return window.myJSObject;");

But it threw me this exception: 

"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.common.collect.Maps$TransformedEntriesMap cannot be cast to java.lang.String
 at testAutomation.FirstTestCase.main(FirstTestCase.java:25)"

If I change the variable result from String to Object, then it seems that it works: 
Object result = jse.executeScript("return window.myJSObject;");
I hope that this was correct.

Comment: @Anik I updated my answer with your comment, I hope it's correct now